# Reference book on Metric Spaces

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

I am trying to study Metric Spaces on my own for some competitive examinations with the essential syllabus for the test including the following topics:

> Metric spaces, compactness, connectedness. Normed Linear Spaces. Spaces of continuous functions
> as examples.

It would be so helpful if you can suggest to me some books with exercises and examples as well to practice along with learning the theory.

Thanks